# Alternative of className Test utility in React application

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, reactjs

I have been facing some difficulties writing test cases in my React application after I moved my external CSS files and refactored into JS objects in order to support `react-inline`

Earlier, for my test cases I have been using `className` to check if the expected `class` exist in my component or not. Since I am not using classes anymore I am having some trouble refactoring my tests. For example,I have been checking whether class `avtar`and `img-rounded` exists if I pass `rounded` style prop in my avatar component.

```
it("should render image with rounded style if style is 'rounded'", done => {
        let user = { displayName: "Foo", avatar: { url: "http://some.url"} };
        renderer.render(
            <UserAvatar user={user} style="rounded" />
        );
        let result = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        expect(result.type).toEqual("img");
        expect(result.props.className).toEqual("avatar img-rounded");
        expect(result.props.src).toEqual("http://some.url");
        done();
    });
```

Now I am adding the associated styles directly into the react component based on the `style` prop passed.

```
_getAvatarStyles() {
        let avatarStyle = {
            borderRadius: "50%"
        };

        if (this.props.style === "circle" || this.props.style === "text-only" || this.props.style === "initials") {
            avatarStyle = {
                borderRadius: "50%"
            };
        } else if (this.props.style === "rounded") {
            avatarStyle = {
                borderRadius: "10%"
            };
        }

        return avatarStyle;
    },
```

Before the refactoring I was adding `className` directly into the component, which looked like as follows:

```
_getAvatarClasses() {
        return classNames({
            "avatar": true,
            "img-rounded": this.props.style === "rounded",
            "img-circle": this.props.style === "circle"
        });
    },
```

Is there any way I can directly check `style` property in the `img` tag. For example, return `true` for circular avatar if the component has `borderRadius: "50%"` or return `true` for rounded avatar if it has `borderRadius: "10%"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a testing library like Sinon.js and spying on the function to test its return value?  It would essentially accomplish the same thing, and it would look something like this:

```
it("should render image with rounded style if style is 'rounded'", done => {
        let user = { displayName: "Foo", avatar: { url: "http://some.url"} };
        renderer.render(
            <UserAvatar user={user} style="rounded" />
        );
        let result = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        let spy = sinon.spy(result, "_getAvatarStyles");
        result.forceUpdate(); //If '_getAvatarStyles()' is called on render, this allows it to be called again
        let expected = {
            borderRadius: "10%"
        };
        expect(spy.returned(expected)).toBe(true);
        done();
});
```

Comment: Just tried using sinon but it gives me the following error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')
` and many warning in sinon lib `WARNING in ./~/sinon/lib/sinon.js
Critical dependencies:
39:25-32 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/sinon/lib/sinon.js 39:25-32
` 
I am importing the library from node_modules `import sinon from "sinon";`

Comment: @zaq Sorry I did not see this comment until today.  Yes, you can't include Sinon by using `require` and such.  It needs to be included in your test runner's configuration where your test framework is included.  So wherever you specify your test framework (looks like either Mocha or Jasmine), include Sinon as well.  For example, I use the Karma test runner, so I need to include it in my Karma configuration file like this: `frameworks: ['jasmine', 'sinon', 'browserify'],`